# 'ContentView_Previews' is not a member type of error

Tags: swiftui

'ContentView_Previews' does not compile if ContentView references an external object.

If I remove all references to @ObservedObject, preview compiles.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var fancyTimer = FancyTimer()

    var body: some View {

    Text("\(fancyTimer.timerValue)")
       .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class FancyTimer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timerValue: Int = 0

    init() {

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) 
        { timer in
           self.timerValue += 1
        }
     }
   }
```

Error is: 'ContentView' is not a member type of 'FancyTimer'

Comment: Meant to include this is Xcode 11 GM Seed.

Comment: The code you posted compiles and runs. Is this a compile-time error? If so, what line is the error on, and what part of the line does Xcode highlight?

Comment: The Preview fails to compile: Error is: 'ContentView' is not a member type of 'FancyTimer'. App runs fine but no preview.

Comment: The code is from a link where the preview compiled. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VioWHKN1eKs

Comment: I had the same issue when I created a project called UnitConverter. [This](https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/52) bug showed me that it was a naming issue with my app. I don't think there is a Foundation/UIKit class called FancyTimer, but maybe it'll help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 29):

Often the problem is that you created a class, a struct, or enum that has the same name as the module you are in.

Here, odds are that "FancyTimer" is also the name of your project, which triggers the error.

Try to change the class name.

Comment: This happened to me. Great catch. Don't name anything (class, struct, enum) to be the same as your project name or the preview gets confused.

Comment: Same problem here, I was going crazy, thanks Louis_Lac

Comment: This was my issue, I had stupidly named my test project the same name as a Foundation class

Comment: This may not be a bug, but it's unacceptable. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 10):

Changing display name and bundle identifier in general settings fixed this issue for me in Xcode 11.1.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this, and clicking the "Diagnostics" button on the Preview panel showed me the problem. Is your project called "FancyTimer"? If so, what is happening is that the compiler is trying to reference FancyTimer.ContentView_Previews, and is failing because it's not a sub-type of that class. Basically you're getting a conflict between project name and class name.

Comment: Thanks! It is hard to find, I change project name to a different one with one of class name, then this problem is gone. I met this when writing Apple's Landmark tutorial, where I made project name as `Landmark` and it is same with one of class name.

Answer (score 4):

My projectname was the same as one of the Foundation's classes. Changing the Projectname fixed the issue.

Comment: Same here, in my case I had set my "Product Name" in the build ssettings to be simply "App" (for common `import App` statements in multiple projects on code reuse) which now contradicts with the new `App` type in SwiftUI. Renaming the "Product Name" (which the Module Name is derived from) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be gone in Xcode 11 GM Seed 2